# limit users to mobile web site

Tags: firebase, ionic3, angular5, firebase-hosting

I am developing a progressive web app using ionic 3 hosted in firebase. My need is to restrict the users to use only mobile version (m.mysite.com, I assume I have to buy sub-domain). 
When the user opens my site (mysite.com) from the desktop, I want to show the welcome message and convey it works only in mobile.

So I have 2 questions in this context:

How can I divert the mysite.com to m.mysite.com when the request comes from mobile?

How can I detect from the app that the request came from the desktop browser so that I can show the appropriate message?

I am not clear how can I use firebase add another site option for my need.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Hosting does not offer any device detection capabilities. If you want something like that, you'll either have to do it client-side, or use a product where you can run server-side code yourself to detect it. You might want to check out Cloud Functions for the latter, but I'll admit that I'm not sure if it'll work there either.

But... if you're building a **progressive** web app, why do you need to serve separate content to mobile and desktop users? One of the main motivators for PWA is that you serve one set of content to all users, and progressively enable features as they are available on the user's platform.

Comment: I can think of doing a device detection on the client side. My intention is to have a mobile-only service but it should not be dependent on play store or app store which is the case if I go for a hybrid or native apps.